# NumPy slicing: All except one array entry

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

What is the best way to exclude exact one NumPy array entry from an operation?
I have an array `x` containing `n` values and want to exclude the `i`-th entry when I call `numpy.prod(x)`. I know about `MaskedArray`, but is there another/better way?

Comment: Assuming it's not an operation that has to be done over a specific axis and the i-th entry is guaranteed not to be 0, you can do `np.prod(x) / x[i]`.

Comment: @Reti43 Unless `numpy` optimises, that is *extremely* inefficient

Comment: The `i`-th element which should be excluded is zero, so `np.prod(x) / x[i]` doesn't work...

Comment: @Divakar My answer exactly!

Comment: @Divakar `numpy.prod(x)` is calculated inside a loop and `i` is the loop index. So if I change the `i`-th value, I have to set it back after `numpy.prod(x)`.

Comment: It sounds like you want to exclude zeros from a product. Do you want to exclude one entry because you have only one zero in this case? Overall, `np.prod(x[x != 0])` should be clear and fast enough. Can you qualify what *better* way you'd be looking for? More pythonic? Memory efficient? Speed? Fewer keystrokes?

Comment: @joe-92 Correct me if I'm misunderstanding what you are saying, but removing the `i`th element does not modify the `i` variable

Comment: @joe-92 Yeah, store the value temporarily somewhere and set it back  afterwards. I would think that would be the most efficient one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the simplest would be

```
np.prod(x[:i]) * np.prod(x[i+1:])
```

This should be fast and also works when you don't want to or can't modify x.

And in case x is multidimensional and i is a tuple:

```
x_f = x.ravel()
i_f = np.ravel_multi_index(i, x.shape)
np.prod(x_f[:i_f]) * np.prod(x_f[i_f+1:])
```

Comment: Interesting and very pythonic approach, +1.

Comment: @Sqoshu Oh, thanks. More often than not on SO I'm getting crucified for being unpythonic, so this is a nice change.

Comment: Also note that the product of an empty array is 1, so even if the ith element to exclude is the first or the last one, this will still work.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`np.delete`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html) whch removes an element from a one-dimensional `array`:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(1, 5)  
i = 2
y = np.prod(np.delete(x, i)) # gives 8
```

Comment: This should be comparatively slow because `np.delete` if I'm not mistaken creates a new array with new data.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any better way, honestly. Even without knowing the NumPy functions, I would do it like:

```
#I assume x is array of len n
temp = x[i] #where i is the index of the value you don't want to change

x = x * 5
#...do whatever with the array...

x[i] = temp
```

If I understand correctly, your problem is one dimensional? Even if not, you can do this the same way.

EDIT:
I checked the `prod` function and in this case I think you can just replace the value u don't want to use with 1 (using `temp` approach I've given you above) and later just put in the right value. It is just a in-place change, so it's kinda efficient. The second way you can do this is just to divide the result by the `x[i]` value (assuming it's not 0, as commenters said).

Answer (score 1):

As [**`np.prod`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.prod.html) is taking the **product** of all the elements in an `array`, if we want to exclude one element from the solution, we can set that element to `1` first in order to ignore it (as `p * 1 = p`).

So:

```
>>> n = 10
>>> x = np.arange(10)
>>> i = 0
>>> x[i] = 1
>>> np.prod(x)
362880
```

which, we can see, works:

```
>>> 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 * 6 * 7 * 8 * 9
362880
```

Comment: if you set it to NaN you can use `numpy.nanprod` but hardly ever matters i guess

Answer (score 0):

You could use a list comprehension to index all the points but 1:

```
i = 2
np.prod(x[[val for val in range(len(x)) if val != i]])
```

or use a set difference:

```
np.prod(x[list(set(range(len(x)) - {i})])
```